# html form button run command php exec

Tags: php, linux, bash, button, exec

I'm trying to learn how to change some debian system settings using html and php.  I have a few bash scripts that do things for me and I want to do them through a web app.

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to change the SSID name in a file called /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf.

Change SSID Name: _____Enter New SSID_____ [Button]

Once someone typed in the new SSID name and hit the button then I would have php exec a bash script or just a SED command to replace the text in the /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf and then display if it was successful or not.  I'm assuming I would use functions and if/then/else.  I've made some decent bash scripts to automate certain things and want to dive into web.  I know and understand HTML really well, and PHP doesn't seem too hard to figure out.

How can I accomplish something like this?

I've tried making a button without user input, but can't get that to work so haven't tried a text box yet.  Assuming permissions and found something about adding Nginx or www-data to sudo.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('echo Hello World'); } ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="button">Run</button>
</form>
```

(I modified this code from another post I found, but isn't displaying Hello World on the page.)

Comment: This wont echo out any thing, You have to do something like: `echo exec("echo \"hello world\"");`. Exec returns the value from the bash, not echo.

Answer (score 1):

As in your code, you have just called `exec()` method and passed a bash command, the output is returned to the function and not echo-ed or printed. You need to echo out the returned string or anything like:

```
<?php
echo exec("echo \"Hello World\");
?>
```

Reference here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

maybe authority is limited,try `{ exec('sudo echo Hello World'); }`

1. try `echo exec('whoami');` whether it can work
2. echo $_POST[] to judge if the value existed
3. mybe the  command has syntax error

mybe you just need to show the result

```
{ echo exec('sudo echo Hello World'); }
```

Comment: I was digging around some more and found this that displays output.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code somewhere else that works out for the button.  Now how can I use an input text box and pass that variable to SED command in linux?

```
<?php

echo
"<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='use_button' value='something' />
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['use_button']))
{
    echo "hey";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run the echo as user www-data than where will the echo show up?

echo it into a file that you can use

```
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
    shell_exec("echo $_POST['button'] > /tmp/ssid");

}
```

than use a shell script to do what you want with the ssid.